# how to make api call each time different section is getting displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am creating one application using react redux. I am having one issue. I want to make endpoint call as user scrolls down for different sections. Can someone suggest how to make endpoint call as user scrolls down or what is the best way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Is your issue how to build this endpoint (backend) OR you have ready endpoint, but you don't know how to integrate it with React+Redux (front-end)

Comment: I already have endpoint. I want to make a call each time user scrolls down. in my application.

Comment: What I want to ask is like facebook if u scrolls down new call is getting made and content gets updated as I think same way I have to build in my app. I am already showing all data after calling endpoint but now I have to do this. Can u suggest me how things can be done. thanks

Comment: alright.. if i got time i will reply

Answer (score 0):

You could use a npm package like [react-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll) to achieve this. You can pass the infinite scroll component a loadFunc that will be called when the user scrolls down.